# Problema modulo OCI8 PHP

Tags: php7, apache2, oracle-12c, rhel

Estoy intentando instalar OCI8 en una maquina RHEL8 con PHP 7.2.24 y APACHE 2.4 para conectar con una BD ORACLE 12.1 y no consigo que me aparezca el módulo OCI en PHPINFO(). A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

**1º Instale los paquetes RPM como usuario root, por ejemplo:**

rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm

**2º Instale la libreria libnsl, puesto que PHP me mostraba una alerta de que faltaba esta libreria**

sudo dnf install libnsl

**3º Export de LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib

**4º Connectar a la BD por SQL**

/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin/sqlplus test/test@localhost/bdtest

Correcto, puedo conectarme y hacer cualquier consulta a través de SQL.

**5º Instalar modulo oci8 para PHP**

pecl install oci8

cuando me pregunta la instalación la ruta la especifico:

instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib

**6º Edito el fichero php.ini y habilito la extensión:**

extension=oci8.so

**7º Reinicie Apache**

service httpd restart

**8º Verifico phpinfo();**

No muestra el módulo oci en phpinfo();

En cambio, sí lanzo a través de cmd #php -m, veo como el módulo si está instalado.

No doy con la solución, agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Normalmente hay dos archivos PHP.ini, el de web y el de cli. Debes estar seguro que está activa la librería en ambos. Revisa eso

Comment: En principio por lo que veo solo tengo un PHP.ini. En el phpinfo, solo figura este: Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini